# Is there a Wild Hunt in Pathfinder?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, monsters, golarion

I am not sure if I am delusional, but I seem to recall reading about a Pathfinder version of [The Wild Hunt](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wild_Hunt). It wasn't explicitly called that, but something else, so I haven't been able to find it by brute searching. Has there been any write up of that anywhere? In a bestiary? In a Pathfinder Adventure Path?

Or am I confusing it in my memory with the headless horseman.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Yes, there is a Wild Hunt in Pathfinder

In 2017 there was a Pathfinder release, [Bestiary 6](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/31977/is-there-a-wild-hunt-in-pathfinder#comment223651_31997), that included The Wild Hunt.  You can also find it [in the PFSRD](https://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/monster-listings/fey/wild-hunt/).

Answer (score 2):

**There's no Wild Hunt in the PFSRD**

Theoretically all of Pathfinder's content is Open Gaming content, which means that if it's not in the PFSRD, it's not in the game at all. There might be something for you in a sourcebook somewhere, but I doubt it.

**You Might be Thinking 3.5**

*Monster Manual V* published The Wild Hunt as a creature, though in terms of being accurate to the myth or a level-appropriate challenge he's a little sad. Still, that may be where you remember it from and porting it to Pathfinder would be easy enough.

Comment: All of the Pathfinder *rules* are Open Gaming content, but the world setting is not.  The PFSRD is also only the unofficial index of the non-setting specific information, and also includes lots of third party stuff.

Comment: That being said, I think that the answer itself is right - I don't know of anything like the Wild Hunt in the Golarian setting.

Comment: Is there anything you could add about the Headless Horseman, since the OP mentioned it?

Comment: I'm not terribly familiar with him. He's not similar to the legends of the Wild Hunt, nor is he particularly fey. I'm not sure how the two would get conflated.

Comment: The reason I can get them confused is that both are things of legend that stalk people at night. In Pathfinder they called the headless horseman a dullahan, a name that was not "headless horseman". So it got into my head that I couldn't just look up the name in an index and expect to find it. Maybe that was why I couldn't find the Wild Hunt.

Comment: On April 26th 2017 pathfinder will release bestiary 6 which will contain stats for the Wild Hunt.